# Detecting Firefox Nightly

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, nightly-build

I've been using firefox's nightly build for a while, and today I noticed an issue with my site (css3's column-width property / jquery, specifically). I've been trying to solve this but no success until now, so all I wanted was to switch to an alternate stylesheet, like with IE. there's any way to detect the nightly build? thanks!

Comment: `if (time < morning && time > evening) { must be nightly? }`

Comment: @Jace - If it's before morning and after evening, it must must be Nightly? Seriously, there's no way to do this, and browser sniffing is not recommended. Feature detection is the way to go here!

Comment: You are trying to accommodate bugs in an unstable version of a browser?  Is that really how you want to spend your valuable time?

Comment: @Dennis I'd upvote your answer a million times if I could!

Comment: For things like this (how css affects how things look on the screen) there is usually no method available in javascript to detect the feature/bug so this is probably the few times that browser detection becomes necessary. Having said that, the correct answer is to report a bug to the firefox team since this is a development/unreleased version of the browser.

Comment: Can you please file the bug so it can get fixed?

Comment: If someone is running a non-stable version of software, they take a conscious risk that it might not work correctly in all situations. It's really not something that should be fixed on the web site or is reasonable to spend time on--the bug might be fixed even before you get the solution on the server and the work has been for nothing.

Comment: @adeneo: You're completely wrong.  This is the correct code:  


`var a = new Date().getTime() % 864e5 / 36e5 + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60;
if (a < 6 || a > 18) {
    var b = document.createElement('link');
    b.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    b.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    b.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/test.css');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b);
}`

Comment: thanks guys, now I realised this was a dumb question (I wrote in a naivety impulse). in fact, the time I've had spent making responsive column-width to work in stable browsers alone should be more then enough to give it a rest.